# React native iOS library not found after updating

Tags: ios, react-native

After I update an already existing React Native library, should i relink it again?.

```
ld: library not found for -lBranch-SDK
```

in addition,when I run react-native-link I get

```
react-native-branch ERR! Failed to add file to project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linking just sets up your native projects to link to the module in your node_modules. Unless there is a major change to the module, you only need to do it once.

For iOS, this will modify your `.pbxproj` file, updating your targets and adding links to the framework (if needed) and the `.xcodeproj` in `node_modules/<module>`

For android, it will modify your `settings.gradle` file to include the project from node_modules. It will also update your `build.gradle` to compile the new library, and it will modify your `MainApplication.java` file to add the new lib to react.